# How do I limit bouncing of physics objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a lot of poker chips using Unity.

But poker chips are moving like a spring.

I want to implement poker chip in real world using Unity physics.

I tried modifiying the value on Rigidbody (Mass, Drag, Angular Dag, etc.)

and also tried modifiying Physics Material.

But Those didn't work.

I want to remove bounce of poker chips.

Sorry for my bad english.

please help me.

Here is my link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lw02Jkpfw2I

and a poker chip prefab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXWK5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your problem can be solved by adding a physics material.
Right click in the project hierachy and create a new [Phsyic Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) and set its values to something like this. I have named the object `ZeroBounce`.
[image]

Add the Physics Material to the colliders of your chips **and** your floor.
[image]

You should immediately see a better result.

---

If the above solution doesn't satisfy you you could also add a script that limits the velocity of the chips. It will slowly lower its vertical speed to zero if it is going up. This will result in a small bounce which I think is a bit more realistic. A damp value of 10 looks pretty smooth to me.
 You can also just straight up set the y velocity to zero like this: `currentVelocity.y = 0;` instead of the lerp method. Then you won't have any bounce at all.

```
public float damp;

void FixedUpdate(){
    var currentVelocity = rigidbody.velocity;
  
     if (currentVelocity.y <= 0f) 
         return;
      
     currentVelocity.y = Mathf.Lerp(currentVelocity.y, 0, damp * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
      
     rigidbody.velocity = currentVelocity;
}
```

Comment: I would also set the `Bounce Combine` to minimum rather than average. It assures regardless of what other object the chips hit, it will always be 0 bounciness.

Comment: Thank you so much.
It didn't solve my problem perfecly.
But It give me many possibilities.
I will try to solve this problem using this.
Really thank you